# stemming of a word without Regex

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

Is it possible to stem words without using Regex in F#?

I want to know how can I write a F# function which inputs a string and stems it.

eg.

```
input = "going"
output = "go"
```

I can't find a way to write the code without using the regex: .*ing\b and replace function which would be almost like doing in C# without any advantage.

Semi pseudo code of what I am trying to write is:

```
let stemming word = 
   match word
    |(word-"ing")+ing -> (word-"ing")
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But how can you stem these verbs: `dying`, `hoping` and `jogging`?

Comment: yeah true. im trying to implement a simple stemmer to start with. then I wud add more conditions.

Comment: @pad For those ones cud use -> (word-"ing")+"e"? and (word-"ing")-"g" etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function applying the simplest stemming rule:

```
let (|Suffix|_|) (suffix: string) (s: string) =
    if s.EndsWith(suffix) then
        Some(s.Substring(0, s.Length - suffix.Length))
    else
        None

let stem = function
    | Suffix "ing" s -> s
    | _ -> failwith "Not ending with ing"
```

[Parameterized active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) makes pattern matching more readable and more convenient in this case. If stemming rules get complicated, you could update active patterns to keep the `stem` function unchanged.

Comment: perfect. this is what i was searcihng on how to use the string library and active patterns.

Answer (score 4):

A quick bit of googling reveals just how complex stemming is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming

The standard seems to be the "Porter Algorithm", it seems several people have ported it to .NET, I count two C# versions and a VB.net version on the "The Porter Stemming Algorithm" homepage:
http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/

I would use one of these libraries from F# to do the stemming.

Comment: thats always an option. but for experimental work what approach wud u recomend? Parse the word and do a substring search and then replace the indexes manually?

Comment: Yes, probably, F#'s list slicing gives quite a nice way to access sub-strings: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/12/09/f-zen-array-slices.aspx